# Strange performance test results for LAMP site

Tags: php, mysql, performance

We have an online application of large amount of data in tables ranging usually from 10+ million in each table.

The performance hits i am facing is in reporting modules  where some charts and tables are displayed loads very slow.

Assuming that total time = PHP execution time + MYSQL query time + http response time

To verify this when i open phpmyadmin which again another web app.

If i click a table with 3 records (SELECT * from table_name) = total time for displaying is 1 - 1.5 seconds. i can see mysql query time 0.0001 sec

When I click a table with 10 million records = total time is 7 -8 second and mysql query time being again close to 0.0001 sec

shouldnt the page load time be the sum of mysql and script run times ? why it loads slow when mysql rows has larger data even mysql says it took same time.

Comment: Are you `LIMIT`ing the query or you're selecting all of the records?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin will automatically append a `limit` clause you your query whether you want it or not (just to expand the above comment).

Comment: Are the 7-8 seconds the sum of PHP execution time + http response time?  How are you measuring this?

Comment: thanks for the responses, so it appends limit. Btw i am measuring total time using firebug which should be the sum of all 3 assuming request is reached quickly.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin uses LIMIT, so that's an irrelevant comparison.

You should use EXPLAIN to see why your query is so awfully slow. 10 million is a small dataset (assuming average row size) and shouldn't take anywhere near 7 seconds.

Also, your method of counting the execution time is flawed. You should measure by timing the individual parts or your script. If SQL is your bottleneck, start optimizing your table or query.

Comment: sorry for late reply but now i have made an script with form that can run arbitrary  query. I hope this should not add LIMIT. I measured time by placing microtime() before and after the mysql_query().